# Проблема с генерацией случайных вещественных чисел

Tags: c, генерация-случайных-данных

Товарищи,как сгенерировать случайное вещественное число в определенном значении.
Как создать целое то и ежу понятно rand() и в путь,а вот с вещественным не разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

В диапазоне от `a` до `b`:

```
float c = a + rand()*((float)(b - a))/RAND_MAX;
```

Comment: Сейчас проверю,заранее спасибо)

Comment: А это ничего, что когда `rand()` даст `RAND_MAX`, то получится `a+b-a+1==b+1`, а не `b`?

Comment: А можно ли прикрутить srand()? У меня ошибку стоп 0x00000000000000000 выдает,видимо время переустановить шиндовс...

Comment: @ФеликсАргаиль, да. srand(time(NULL)) будет генерировать случайные числа в зависимости от времени

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @ФеликсАргаиль Только, надеюсь, вы помните, что `srand` вызывается один раз, а не перед каждым `rand`? А то и такое, случается, делают :)

Comment: а ещё стоит помнить, что это даёт только `log2(RAND_MAX)` бит энтропии (обычно 15-16), что меньше, чем мантиса `float`...